# MJPEG over HTTP camera streaming for libcamera?

Tags: camera, libcamera

I have (had) a little python based web server that I used with a Pi4 with a NOIR camera to periodically watch my workbench when I wasn't there. It is (was) using picamera, which it seems isn't going to be supported going forward. So is there an equivalent project based on libcamera that will make an http server that just serves a simple frame window with streaming MJPEG in it?

Comment: I've been trying to find the answer to this for days. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require enabling the legacy camera stack. I want to use the libcamera package but view the output in a browser window. I also want the stream to start no matter what and not just when a client connects.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already come across it, the alpha release of Picamera2 has many useful examples of controlling the libcamera stack with Python. The mjpeg-server.py example 'does what it says on the tin'.
https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2

Answer (score 0):

If you are good with mp4/h264 too, try [fmp4streamer](https://github.com/soyersoyer/fmp4streamer). It uses the old camera stack's v4l2 driver (bcm2835-camera).

Comment: Enabling the old camera stack doesn't feel right. I am ideally looking to be able to use libcamera-vid to stream output no matter what that I can view/read from in a browser. Even if I have to use a proxy server or something I'd rather that than use the deprecated camera features